# How do I display a LeafletJS default OpenStreetMap map with all English labels

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, openstreetmap

Simple question.. what parameters can I add to change the labels to English? Is there another map tile provider I can use for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one here https://rapidapi.com/MapTilesApi/api/maptiles has raster tiles with English labels for Leaflet.